# saving data of firstActivity in database after clicking the secondActivity's button

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-activity

i have two activities,like login.java and sync.java, in login.java i have two edit Text fields that is 'id' and 'password' and a login button, in sync.java i have a button named sync, so what i want to do is save the login activity's 'id' field in database after clicking the button of sync activity. 
P.S : i am making an android app and using MySQL sever to save the data.

This is login.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.registerLink:
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(login.this, register.class);
            startActivity(registerIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.bLogin:
            if (etUserId.getText().length() == 0 || etPassword.getText().length() == 0) {
                etUserId.setError( "Fill in the field" );
                etPassword.setError("Fill in the field");}
            else{
                id = etUserId.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String method = "login";
                backgroundTask bTask = new backgroundTask(this);


bTask.execute(method, id, password);
                }
```

This is sync.java

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String method = "sync";
        backgroundTask bTask = new backgroundTask(this);
        bTask.execute(method);
        //startActivity(new Intent(this,synchronization.class));
    }
```

This is background.java where database stuff is going on

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/app/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/app/login.php";
    String sync_url = "http://10.0.2.2/app/sync.php";
    //192.168.10.9
    if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String id = params[1];
        String password = params[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("sync")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sync_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
     if(result.equals("login successful"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, sync.class));
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(result.equals("sync successful"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, synchronization.class));
    }
```

}
}